# Extra Spaces after custom prefix [Discord.py]

Tags: sqlite, discord, discord.py

I tried to make a custom prefix commands, but just to make it efficient, i'm going to add extra spaces into it, if the prefix containing a alphabetical character(a-z), but when I use this, it says that the new_prefix is referenced before assignment, it works, I'm just wondering why?

````py
    @command(name='prefix')
    @has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
    @guild_only()
    async def prefix_cmd(self, ctx, *, prefix=None):
        if prefix is None:
            async with connect('dumbo.db') as db:
                prefix_db = await db.execute(f"SELECT Prefix FROM guilds WHERE GuildID = {ctx.guild.id}")
                server_prefix = await prefix_db.fetchone()
            await ctx.send(f"{emotrue} This server prefix is: `{server_prefix[0]}`.")
        else:
            for spaced in alphabet:
                if spaced in prefix.lower():
                    new_prefix = f'{prefix} '
            async with connect('dumbo.db') as db:
                await db.execute(f"UPDATE guilds SET Prefix = ? WHERE GuildID = ?", (f'{new_prefix}', ctx.guild.id))
                await db.commit()
            await ctx.send(f"{emotrue} This server prefix is now updated to `{prefix}`.")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you define `new_prefix` in the if statement, so `new_prefix` will only be a thing if that `if` statement is True which can sometimes be False, so it says used before defining.

If you do `new_prefix = ''` at the starting of the command or else statement, it should resolve the error

Comment: Actually, I have to set the new_prefix into `new_prefix = prefix`, so if the spaces aren't triggered, it will add the normal prefix, it would be '' or None if you did it with `new_prefix = ''` but anyway thanks!